# Letsencrypt issue: The request message was malformed :: Error creating new authz :: DNS name does not have enough labels

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, encryption

I am trying to setup encryption on AWS EC2 machine. When I run below command

`sudo certbot --nginx -d sitename -d www.sitename.com`

Then I get above error.

I edited `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file and added below lines

`server_name sitename www.sitename.com;`

Any idea why am I getting above error.

I am using this tutorial.

https://blog.cloudboost.io/setting-up-an-https-sever-with-node-amazon-ec2-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-46f869159469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining about the suffix in your certificate. The name `www.sitename.com` is valid but you also have `sitename` with no suffix. You need to make this `sitename.com`.

So, you should regenerate your certificate with something like

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d sitename.com -d www.sitename.com
```

Comment: I didn't add .com to the first one in AWS either. Should I do it for both in this command as well as in aws console?

Comment: Yes, you need to add .com to both

Comment: I'd met same issue. When i run command `./letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto -debug`, the error occured. Because the option is incorrect. -debug (with one hyphen) option mean  -d ebug and ebug is not valid domain. It's should be --debug